# Incompatible Typescript types for arrays of generic interfaces

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a custom event mechanism for my application, and am struggling with defining accurate types for it. IMHO these typings should be correct, but Typescript doesn't seem to infer the correct type of the array of listeners. It works when I assert the listener array to `const listeners = eventlisteners[kind] as XEventlistener<T>[]`, but I'm not a big fan of assertions in Typescript. Can someone explain why Typescript isn't able to infer the correct type for that array? Or are my typings wrong? Here's the code:

```
export const enum XEventTypes {
    CONFIG_UPDATE,
    ACTION_FINISHED
}

export type XEventListenerCollection = {
    [T in XEventTypes]: XEventListener<T>[];
};


export interface XEvent<S extends XEventTypes> {
    kind: S;
    detail: DetailTypes[S];
}

export interface DetailTypes {
    [XEventTypes.CONFIG_UPDATE]: string;
    [XEventTypes.ACTION_FINISHED]: number;
}

export type XEventListener<T extends XEventTypes> = (event: XEvent<T>) => void;

const eventListeners: XEventListenerCollection = {
    [XEventTypes.CONFIG_UPDATE]: [],
    [XEventTypes.ACTION_FINISHED]: []
};

export function addEventListener<T extends XEventTypes>(kind: T, listener: XEventListener<T>): void {
    // this doesn't compile without the assertion
    const listeners = eventListeners[kind] as XEventListener<T>[]; 

    if (listeners.indexOf(listener) > -1)  {
        return;
    }

    listeners.push(listener);
}
```

Comment: Unresolved generic usually lead to type assertions. Typescript is very limited in what it can prove with them. In this case it is difficult for to track that `listener` is compatible `listeners`

Comment: I thought it's pretty easy to determine because T is explicitly defined as a key from `XEventTypes`, the lookup for the array happens in `eventListeners[kind]`, where `kind` must be of type T. Next lookup happens on `XEventListenerCollection`, right? We want to lookup T, and the value of property T must be `XEventListener<T>[]`. I don't understand the issue here. Or do I misunderstand how Typescript resolves types?